# Generate a prime number in a range with fixed $n$ most significant bits

Tags: prime-numbers, binary

I'm new to Mathematica so my question might be trivial.

How do I generate a $200-bit$ prime with the condition that the 10 most significant bits in its binary representation are equal to some binary string (for example $1001110011$)?

I know that I can use `RandomPrime[{2^199, 2^200 - 1}]` to generate primes in the required range, but how do I guarantee the previous condition?

Comment: One can use `NextPrime`. (1) Set your initial bits. (2) Pick a random integer `rand` between the lowest and highest values that have those initial bits. (3) Take `NextPrime[rand]`. (4) If it exceeds the max, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the valid range by using `BitShiftLeft` on the string and its successor:

```
RandomPrime[{BitShiftLeft[2^^1001110011,     190],
             BitShiftLeft[2^^1001110011 + 1, 190] - 1}]
```

Comment: @Shadowfirex - don't ask additional questions in a `Comment`. Start a new `Question`. If appropriate to add context, link back to the original question.

Comment: Alright, moved the comment to a separate question.