# Generate a prime number satisfying a condition

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Building on the same context of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164443/generate-a-prime-number-with-a-condition)

Is it possible to enforce constraints on the properties of the generated prime? For example, I'm trying to find a prime $p$ in the range specified in the question on top with the property that $5 \in QR_p$ which mean that there exists a number $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 5\pmod p$

Comment: I'd generate a number of primes, and then test each.

Comment: could you at least put your criteria in mathematica form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
randprime[] := RandomPrime[{BitShiftLeft[2^^1001110011, 190], 
  BitShiftLeft[2^^1001110011 + 1, 190] - 1}]

NestWhile[randprime[] &, 0, JacobiSymbol[5, #] != 1 &]
```

> ```
> 984243528019146533777127966928980517167883028753863934494399
> ```